# CSS/HTML : float left not working when I zoom out the browser

Tags: html, css, css-float, border

I have a simple HTML like below :

```
<div id="main_container">
 <div class="floated_box">box 1</div>
 <div class="floated_box">box 2</div>
 <div class="floated_box">box 3</div>
 <div class="floated_box">box 4</div>
 <div class="floated_box">box 5</div>
 <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

and the following css for my html elements :

```
#main_container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 2px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.floated_box {
  border: 1px solid #990000;
  display:block;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 198px;
}
```

the code above gives me exactly what I want :

[image: result of code above]

however, there is a mirror bug I've found, that is when I zoom out the browser (**use ctrl + scroll wheel of mouse**), my floated elements are all destroyed, like the image below :

[image: result of code when zoom out the browser]

When I delete the css code `border` for my floated element, the zoom out doesn't destroy the floated elements any more. So I figured out that maybe the `border` property destroy the floated elements.

How could I do for fixing the bug if I always need the `border` property for floated elements?  Thanks in advance.

Here is the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sk4qm2w5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `border-box` [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to include the border when specifying the width of the elements:

```css
#main_container {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 2px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 5px;
}
.floated_box {
    border: 1px solid #990000;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 198px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_container">
    <div class="floated_box">box 1</div>
    <div class="floated_box">box 2</div>
    <div class="floated_box">box 3</div>
    <div class="floated_box">box 4</div>
    <div class="floated_box">box 5</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

An alternative method is to use negative margins to account for the border width:

```
margin: 0px -1px;
```

Answer (score 1):

just change width to : 49% : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sk4qm2w5/1/)

```
 #main_container {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 border: 2px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 5px;
}

.floated_box {
    border: 1px solid #990000;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 49%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution that might work for you.

```
#main_container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 2px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 5px;
}
.floated_box {
    border: 1px solid #990000;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_container">
 <div class="floated_box">box 1</div>
 <div class="floated_box">box 2</div>
 <div class="floated_box">box 3</div>
 <div class="floated_box">box 4</div>
 <div class="floated_box">box 5</div>
 <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sk4qm2w5/2/

You might also wanna try which width suits you the best.
*width: 45%;* was only for making the point.